# Client machine unresponsive when X11 forwarding an application

Tags: 16.04, ssh, performance, x11-forwarding

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Desktop version) on my laptop. Performance is more than adequate for my needs: I'm able to open and close windows and surf the Internet just fine.

Then I open Terminal and run this command to connect to my Raspberry Pi (halfway across the Internet) that's configured for X11 Forwarding:

```
ssh -X pi@raspberrypi
```

Everything still appears to run quite well up to this point, but if I start a browser in the Terminal window (I've tried both chromium-browser and midori, both behave the same) then *everything* seems to grind to a halt on the Ubuntu client. Windows become gray and unresponsive. Clicked buttons take ages to respond. The behavior continues until I eventually manage to stop the X11 forwarded browser.

While Ubuntu is running slowly, if I run `top` on the Raspberry PI then I don't see anything obnoxious using up the CPU, nor do I see anything on the Ubuntu client when I run System Monitor (though it takes a long time for the window to display).

What's causing such a dramatic slow down? Yes, I appreciate there might be some latency due to difference in location between the X11 server and client, but this is affecting all the local processes on the Ubuntu client too.